# Exception when calling getVideoId after direct upload in youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

This link to google group has a question that causes me a doubt:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/youtube-api-gdata/fYbKwNP5Dj8/6l7B4q9s2fUJ

Why the solution is  `$newEntry->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);` when google dev guide says that must be `$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);` ?

(enter https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php and look for the first occurrence of `$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);`)

Answer (score 0):

`setMajorProtocolVersion` can be called from a service class, a feed or an entry. In the example on Google Groups that you link to, the protocol version is being set for the entry only. In the example from the dev guide, it is being set globally on the service object.